# Filter objects from a list that have the same member

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, vavr

I have a list of objects. The object looks like this:

```
public class Slots {
  String slotType;
  Visits visit;
}


public class Visits {
  private long visitCode;
  private String agendaCode;
  private String scheduledTime;
  private String resourceType;
  private String resourceDescription;
  private String visitTypeCode;
  ...
}
```

I need to find the elements that have the same `agendaCode`, `visitTypeCode` and `scheduledTime` and for the life of me I can't get it done.

I tried this:

```
Set<String> agendas = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
    .map(Slots::getVisit)
    .map(Visits::getAgendaCode)
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

Set<String> visitTypeCode = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
    .map(Slots::getVisit)
    .map(Visits::getVisitTypeCode)
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

Set<String> scheduledTime = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
    .map(Slots::getVisit)
    .map(Visits::getScheduledTime)
    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());

List<Slots> collect = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
    .filter(c -> agendas.contains(c.getVisit().getAgendaCode()))
    .filter(c -> visitTypeCode.contains(c.getVisit().getVisitTypeCode()))
    .filter(c -> scheduledTime.contains(c.getVisit().getScheduledTime()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it's not doing what I thought it would. Ideally I would have a list of lists, where each sublist is a list of Slots objects that share the same `agendaCode`, `visitTypeCode` and `scheduledTime`. I struggle with functional programming so any help or pointers would be great!

This is Java 11 and I'm also using vavr.

Comment: You could possibly take a look at the `filter` logic in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54798478/1746118), that's what shall solve what you're up to I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mentioned you're using vavr, here is the vavr way to solve this question.

Supposed you have your `io.vavr.collection.List` (or `Array` or `Vector` or `Stream` or similar vavr collection) of visits:

```
List<Visits> visits = ...;

final Map<Tuple3<String, String, String>, List<Visits>> grouped =
    visits.groupBy(visit ->
        Tuple.of(
            visit.getAgendaCode(),
            visit.getVisitTypeCode(),
            visit.getScheduledTime()
        )
    );
```

Or with a `java.util.List` of visits:

```
List<Visits> visits = ...;

Map<Tuple3<String, String, String>, List<Visits>> grouped = visits.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        visit ->
            Tuple.of(
                visit.getAgendaCode(),
                visit.getVisitTypeCode(),
                visit.getScheduledTime()
            )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to define a new class with necessaries fields (`agendaCode`, `visitTypeCode` and `scheduledTime`). Don't forget about `equals/hashcode`.

```
public class Visits {
    private long visitCode;
    private String resourceType;
    private String resourceDescription;
    private Code code;
    ...
}
class Code {
    private String agendaCode;
    private String scheduledTime;
    private String visitTypeCode;
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {...}
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {...}
}
```

Then you can use `groupingBy` like:

```
Map<Code, List<Slots>> map = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.getVisit().getCode()));
```

Also you can just implement `equals` method inside `Visits` only for `agendaCode`, `visitTypeCode` and `scheduledTime`. In this case use `groupingBy` by `s.getVisit()`

Answer (score 1):

I love [Ruslan's idea of using Collectors::groupingBy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828946/7421571). Nevertheless, I don't like creating a new class or defining a new `equals` method. Both of them coerces you to a single `Collectors::groupingBy` version. What if you want to group by other fields in other methods?

Here is a piece of code that should let you overcome this problem:

```
slotsResponse.getContent()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> Arrays.asList(s.getVisit().getAgendaCode(), s.getVisit().getVisitTypeCode(), s.getVisit().getScheduledTime())))
    .values();
```

My idea was to create a new container for every needed field (agendaCode, visitTypeCode, scheludedTime) and compare slots on these newly created containers. I would have liked doing so with a simple `Object` array, but it doesn't work - arrays should be compared with Arrays.equals which is not the comparison method used by `Collectors::groupingBy`.

Please note that you should store somewhere or use a method to define which fields you want to group by.

Answer (score 1):

The fields you want to group by are all strings. You can define a function which  concatenate those fields values and use that as key for your groups. Example

```
Function<Slots,String> myFunc = s -> s.getVisit().agendaCode + s.getVisit().visitTypeCode + s.getVisit().scheduledTime;
                               // or s.getVisit().agendaCode +"-"+ s..getVisit().visitTypeCode +"-"+ s.getVisit().scheduledTime;
```

And then group as below:

```
Map<String,List<Slots>> result = slotsResponse.getContent().stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myFunc));
```

Comment: The syntax seems invalid, might just want to try it out on a compiler and the output would be a single entry mapped to a key based on the same logic as `myFunc` to extract the `List<Slots>`. But the approach is good IMHO.

Comment: I meant in the direction that -- 1. the fields are a part of `Visits` and not `Slots` so the Function definition needs to be updated to make it compile. 2. While looking up in the map `result`, one would have to do the same logic of `s.agendaCode + s.visitTypeCode + s.scheduledTime` to form a correct key to lookup.(`result.get`) <-- though that should just be `myFunc` apply if the `Slot` would have been known.

Comment: Also, x=a+b+c=d+e+f they would be grouped into the same group while having different values for the individual components. So concatenation is not guaranteed to be correct.